# porting tigase from derby to hsqldb ... how to call stored Java procedure and throw away (ignore) the result?

Tags: derby, hsqldb

Trying to configure [tigase](http://www.tigase.org/) to use hsqldb (hsqldb-1.8.0.9-1jpp.2) instead of derby (don't ask why, that's not the point) and everything works fine, except for setting some properties in the end. In Derby I had

```
CREATE procedure TigAddUserPlainPw(userId varchar(2049), userPw varchar(255)) 
    PARAMETER STYLE JAVA
    LANGUAGE JAVA
    MODIFIES SQL DATA
    DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
    EXTERNAL NAME 'tigase.db.derby.StoredProcedures.tigAddUserPlainPw';
```

and

```
call TigAddUserPlainPw('db-properties', NULL);
```

When I try to replices this with hsqldb by

```
CREATE ALIAS TigAddUserPlainPw
    FOR "tigase.db.derby.StoredProcedures.tigAddUserPlainPw";
```

and

```
CALL TigAddUserPlainPw('db-properties', NULL);
```

I get this error message

```
[root@tikanga scripts]# ./hsqldb-db-create.sh /var/lib/tigase/db/tigase
SQL Error at '/etc/tigase/database/hsqldb-schema-4-props.sql' line 1:
"CALL TigAddUserPlainPw('db-properties', NULL)"
Wrong data type: [Ljava.sql.ResultSet; in statement [CALL TigAddUserPlainPw(]
```

Any idea, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the signature of the method tigAddUserPlainPw?

Comment: public static void tigAddUserPlainPw(String userId, String userPw, ResultSet[] data) throws SQLException

Comment: source code for it is in https://svn.tigase.org/reps/tigase-server/trunk/src/main/java/tigase/db/derby/StoredProcedures.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the Java static methods as they are. The Result[] parameters are not acceptable to HSQLDB 1.8.x.

It would be easier to convert to HSQLDB 2.0, as its stored procedure support has improved over version 1.8.

Your example shows we need to make some more improvements to HSQLDB to support these procedure declarations.

Comment: Unfortunately, whole point of using hsqldb is to make tigase work on RHEL-5 without installing any additional packages (as there is no official package of Derby for Fedora/RHEL).

Comment: HSQLDB can be bundled with any software (there is no license issue). So can't you just bundle the jar with your software's jars? In any case, your example reminded me to prioritise full support for this type of procedure usage and this will be available in snapshot jars in the next few days and in the next 2.0.1 GA piont release in a week's time. Redhat too will probably start distributing 2.0.x soon.

Comment: The latest HSQLDB 2.0.1 snapshot jar supports the functions. Jar at http://hsqldb.org/support/  The GA release will be out soon.

Comment: This is about packaging tigase for RHEL-5, where of course you cannot package any additional jars (find . -name \*.jar -delete is highly recommended if not required) and upgrades of what's part of RHEL itself (not additional packages on top of it) are highly discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, HSQLDB supports Java functions that return a ResultSet (Fred will correct me if I'm wrong): http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/sqlroutines-chapt.html#N12835

You would need a new method:

```
public static ResultSet tigAddUserPlainPw(
    String userId, String userPw) throws SQLException;
```